# How to make progress label in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make label in Tkinter that shows progres. The destination variable need to be from entry. Label should be updated every time when progress changes

My current code:

```
from tkinter import *


okno = Tk()


x =IntVar()
y = 0
z = 0

def rup():
    x.get()
    z = 0
    while True:
        if z <= x:
            z += 1
            progresLabel['text'] = "{}/{}".format(z, x)
            okno.update_idletasks()
        else:
            break



okno.geometry('200x100')
mainFrame = Frame(okno, width=200, height=100).place()
progresLabel = Label(mainFrame, text="{}/{}".format(x, z)).place(relx=0.35, rely=0.35)
xEntry = Entry(mainFrame, textvariable=x).place(relx=0.2, rely=0.7)
oneButton = Button(mainFrame, text='run', width=5, command=rup).place(relx=0.35, rely=0.05)

okno.mainloop()
```

Unfortunetly get this error

```
if z <= x
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'IntVar'
```

I'm new in python so maybe whole code is wrong

Comment: All your widget references are None because they are assigned the result of `place(...)`.  Also when you want to use the value of `x`, you should use `x.get()` and not `x` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply compare an `int` to an `IntVar`. You need to first invoke the .get method of IntVar:

```
if z <= x.get()
```